# How to create JQWidgets Category listbox Programatically?

Tags: php, jquery, jqxgrid, jqxwidgets, jqwidget

I want to Show JQXListBox with categorized Listbox with Checkboxes, 
I can create it statically.

How Can I create with JQXAdapter programatically (PHP, MYSQL) like this?

If any one knows please help me as soon as possible. Thanks in Advance.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

they have a new feature where you can create it from a select query.

http://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-widgets-demo/demos/jqxlistbox/index.htm#demos/jqxlistbox/listbox-from-select.htm

maybe solves your problem?